# NavMeshAgent stopping before reaching it's destination Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 3D FPS game in Unity using c#. I have an enemy AI using a NavMeshAgent to patrol an area. I have a method that chooses a random location on the map and then tells the enemy to go to that point, and once it gets to that point it is supposed to choose another random point on the map, however it only works some of the times. Sometimes it will stop very near the point but not at the point even though there is nothing telling it to stop yet, and it won't choose a new point. Does anyone know the solution to this?

Here is my script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    
    //Patrolling Area
    public Vector3 walkPoint;
    private bool walkPointSet;
    public float walkPointRange;
    
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
            Patrol();
    }

    void Patrol()
    {
        if (!walkPointSet)
        {
            SearchWalkPoint();
        }

        Vector3 distanceToWalkPoint = transform.position - walkPoint;
        
         //when walk point is reached
         if (distanceToWalkPoint.magnitude < 1f)
         {
             walkPointSet = false;
         }
    }

    void SearchWalkPoint()
    {
        //calculate random point in range
        float randomZ = Random.Range(-walkPointRange, walkPointRange);
        float randomX = Random.Range(-walkPointRange, walkPointRange);
        
        walkPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x + randomX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + randomZ);

        //checks if random walk point is inside of the map
        if (Physics.Raycast(walkPoint, -transform.up, 3f, groundMask))
        {
            walkPointSet = true;
        }
        
        agent.SetDestination(walkPoint);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I added the variables randomX and randomZ to the objects currect x and z position which created some sort of offset that affected certain random values from not being reached. The solution was just to insert randomX and randomZ into their respective points and not add the number to the current position. The updated code is as follows:

```
walkPoint = new Vector3(randomX, transform.position.y, randomZ);
```